# How to summarize rows to columns to get every combination

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It is possible that this was already solved somewhere but I really have no clue what to search for.
My problem is I have a table with a product ID and all possible options for that product.
For a new Interface I have to export all my products with all possible configurations in a line for each configuration.

Lets say I have a desk which can have the lengths 160cm and 180cm and can either be black, brown or gray.

my table then looks something like

```
desk length  160
desk length  180
desk Color   black
desk Color   brown
desk Color   gray
```

as a result for my Interface I need 6 rows which should look like this

```
desk 160 black
desk 160 brown 
desk 160 gray
desk 180 black
desk 180 brown
desk 180 gray
```

it could also be that the desk has more options like height or has 10+ different colors, I just took 2 options here so I could describe my desired result.

I already had a result looking like this

```
pdID    opt1    opt2    opt3    opt4
219     NULL    L       NULL    NULL
219     NULL    R       NULL    NULL
219     NULL    NULL    LF      NULL
219     NULL    NULL    LS      NULL
```

but I'm a bit at loss how to get from there to

```
pdID    opt1    opt2    opt3    opt4
219     NULL    L       LF      NULL
219     NULL    R       LS      NULL
219     NULL    R       LF      NULL
219     NULL    L       LS      NULL
```

Comment: is `desk length 160` in one column or in 3 columns ?

Comment: its 3 Columns, sorry couldn't really figure out how i get this tables formated ...

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe

```
declare @t table (item varchar(10), property varchar(10), value varchar(10))
insert into @t values ('desk', 'length', '160'), ('desk', 'length', '180'), ('desk', 'color', 'black'), ('desk', 'color', 'brown'), ('desk', 'color', 'gray')

select t.item, 
       t.value as length, 
       t2.value as color
from   @t t
  join @t t2 on t.item = t2.item 
            and t2.property = 'color'
where  t.property = 'length'
```

the result is

```
item    length  color
----    -----   ------- 
desk    160     black   
desk    160     brown   
desk    160     gray    
desk    180     black   
desk    180     brown   
desk    180     gray
```

**EDIT**
If you want all combinations together, not just for 'length', you can try this query

```
select t.item, 
       t.value as length, 
       t2.value as color
from   @t t
  join @t t2 on t.item = t2.item 
            and t2.property <> t.property
```

Comment: yeah ok, i could go with that, my only problem is i got around 10 properties i have to join at the moment (could get more) so i would have to make 9 joins and get back to my procedure each time that changes. i hoped for something more "automatic", but if there is no other solution i will go with that. thank you for your time!

Comment: If you put this inside a stored procedure, than you can pass the property you want as parameter. `where t.property = 'length' ` would then become `where t.property = @PropertyName `

Comment: I edited my answer, you can try the query from the edit if this will be automatic enough for your purpose